# C# Creating window - Defining Parent window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, createwindow

I want create using `C#` window with setted parent to my defined handle,
this is a other process window handle.

Anyone know how to do this?

Greetings,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you should be able to achieve what you want by using something like this:

```
class Win32Window : IWin32Window
{
    IntPtr handle;

    public Win32Window(IntPtr handle) { this.handle = handle; }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { return this.handle; }
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    IntPtr targetParent = // Get handle to the parent window

    new MainForm().ShowDialog(new Win32Window(targetParent));
}
```

This will turn `MainForm` a child window of the specified window making it always appear above it. I use `ShowDialog` in the example, but this should also work for `Show`. This is specific for Windows Forms.

In WPF you can try the following:

```
var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(/* your Window instance */);

helper.Owner = // Set with handle for the parent
```

I quickly tried this after showing the WPF window and it seemed to work as expected, but WPF knowledge is not that great.

Comment: Ok i will try this, but .. this is impossible for Window class? I have already code based on Window with XAML.

Comment: I assumed Windows Forms, so this would not be applicable for a WPF Window.

Comment: I updated the answer with a possible solution in WPF, but I don't make any guarantees... :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the Handle will be read-only; therefore, the `.Parent` property is read-only. However, the `.Owner` property has a getter and a setter ([ref. MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx)) ... however, you must have a reference to the Parent window.

<strike>Without more information, I will not be able to provide much more than that.</strike>

If your parent candidate is an *unmanaged* Window, check this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/5ea93903-e9ac-4f5e-8383-be167a74120f).